# An unhandled exception of type System.StackOverflowException occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: .net, asp.net

I wrote a code in ASP.NET that read data from SQL Table and show it in Grid View and using Row Data Bound Event.But when I run the program, this exception arise "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" in indicated statement of the code:

```
    private void BindAllUsers()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, Email, Password, Contact, CreatedOn, CreatedBy,CreatedIP From tbl_Users",con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);       <------(Error occurs in this line)
        gdv_Users.DataSource = ds;
        gdv_Users.DataBind();

    }
```

The RowDataBoundEvent handler is:

```
    protected void gdv_Users_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Style["Cursor"] = "hand";
        e.Row.Cells[0].ToolTip = "Click Here";
        e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onclick","window.open('Details.aspx'?ID=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToString()+"'Details';'width = 735,height= 350,left = 220,top = 300,resizable = 0,scrollbars = 0,status = no')");
    }
```

The BindAllUser Function is called here:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindAllUsers();
    BindDropDown();

}
```

Comment: What do you see in the Visual Studio call stack?

Comment: I guess you are calling BindAllUsers in OnRowDataBoundEvent and since you are biding the grid again its going into an infinite loop. Can you post the RowDataaBound Event Handler?

Comment: @Rachit: Can you also post the code where you are calling the BindAllUsers method?

Comment: How many rows are in your users table?

Comment: @Cybernate: M calling it in Page_Load method

Comment: without using data adapter can you try it with sqldatareader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        private void BindAllUsers()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = con;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, Email, Password, Contact, CreatedOn, CreatedBy,CreatedIP From tbl_Users";
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                gdv_Users.DataSource = ds;
                gdv_Users.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Also check if you are calling this method from OnDataBound Event?

Comment: yes I was calling this method from OnDataBound. Removed, and it works fine. Thanks.